# Show product order details in custom thankyou page - Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm redirecting woocomerce order received page when click on purchase buttom, but i need to show the product order details in my custom thankyou page, do you have any idea how to do this?

this is the code that I use to redirect to my custom thankyou page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirectcustom');
  
function redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'my_url_thankyoupage';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass encrypted order id with url so you will have access to order detail from order id.
this is simple way to complete task otherwise there are many plugins available to change default thank you page